# no Drmaa JNI in java.library.path error

Tags: java, drmaa

Hi I am new to Drmaa and trying to work on it for a project . 
I have installed drmaa.jar from this location http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/d/Downloaddrmaajar.htm in my eclipse and tried a simple project :
Try.java :

```
import org.ggf.drmaa.*;

    public class Try {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws DrmaaException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            SessionFactory factory = SessionFactory.getFactory();
            Session session = factory.getSession();
            session.init("abc ");
            session.exit();
        }

    }
```

When I run this program I get the below error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no DrmaaJNI in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.ggf.drmaa.DrmaaJNI.<clinit>(DrmaaJNI.java:89)
    at org.ggf.drmaa.GridWaySession.<init>(GridWaySession.java:81)
    at org.ggf.drmaa.GridWaySessionFactory.getSession(GridWaySessionFactory.java:33)
    at Example.Try.main(Try.java:10)
```

Can anyone please help me fix it as I am new to this and I have googled about it but couldnt get sufficient information . Thanks . 
I just want to fix this problem so anyone please help .

Comment: You should tell us the link from where you downloaded the drmaa jar file. So we know exactly which jar file you're talking about.

Comment: I didn't ... Someone else did... sorry.

Comment: Can you please answer the question?

Comment: I'm not an expert in these kind of errors, May be this link will help http://lists.globus.org/pipermail/gridway-user/2008-November/000018.html . I will also +1 your question and maybe someone else can help

Comment: The jar file does have the DrmaaJNI.class file so the JVM should find it.